# Swift init struct with JSON.encode memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm using custom `init` method to parse `JSON` data into `Video struct`.

```
extension Video: Codable {
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Video.self, from: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary))
    }
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case duration, nsfw, genres, nextVideo, title, video_thumbnail_9x16, onexone_img, video_script, feature_img, sh_heading, tags, alt_content, video_thumbnail_16x9, pub_date, slug, aspect_ratio, _id, interactive, show, cast_crew, srt, sw_more
    }
}
```

But I can see in instrument `Leaks` profiler that this `int` is causing memory leaks.

[image: Profiler Screenshot]

What is the issue here?

EDIT: More info

As it is been pointed that the leak could be anywhere else and I do see my fetch data method with `closure` in the instrument inspector too. So that might be issue.

Here is the network call process and creation of the `Video` objects in code.

A property `homeVideosDatasource` does the whole job of fetching the data from APIs.

`callHomeVideosAPI` is called from `viewDidLoad`. `callHomeVideosAPI` first fetched a config json, which tells which sections to load in Homescreen. The sections contains `Video` objects (with some other objects, they are causing leaks too).

```
    var homeVideosDatasource = HomeVideosDatasource()
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateFirebaseToken), name: Notification.Name(Constants.fcmToken), object: nil)
        
        notificationUpdate()
        
        updateFirebaseToken()
        
        activityIndicatorView.type = .ballPulse
        activityIndicatorView.color = UIColor(hexString: Constants.kPinkColor)
        
        self.refreshControl.tintColor = .white
        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callAPIs), for: .valueChanged)
        collectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        
        callHomeVideosAPI()
        setupViews()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.init(rawValue: Constants.homeLoadedNotification), object: nil)
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            // Tell Appdelegate that app is loaded
            appDelegate.isHomeLoaded = true
            appDelegate.showVideoDetailFromNotification()
        }
    }
```

```
    private func callHomeVideosAPI() {
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.homeVideosDatasource.fetchDataForHomeVideos { [weak self] (completed, error) in
                
                guard let self = self else { return }
                
                if let error = error {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.view.showMessageTicker(message: error)
                    }
                    return
                }
                
                if completed {
                    // remove sections with no data
                    let homeVideosSectionsWithDataOnly = self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource.filter { (homeVideosSection) -> Bool in
                        if homeVideosSection.datasource.count != 0 {
                            return true
                        } else {
                            return false
                        }
                    }
                    
                    self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource = homeVideosSectionsWithDataOnly
                    
                    self.stopAnimating()
                    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                    self.state = .success
                } else {
                    self.state = .error
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now `HomeVideosDatasource` :

```
class HomeVideosDatasource {
    private var provider = MoyaProvider<ScoopWhoop>(plugins: [CompleteUrlLoggerPlugin()])
    private var scoopWhoopProvider = MoyaProvider<ScoopWhoop>(plugins: [CompleteUrlLoggerPlugin()])
    
    var datasource = [HomeVideosSection]()
    private var dataCount = 0
    
    func fetchDataForHomeVideos(_ closure: @escaping (Bool, String?) -> Void) {
        
        if !(NetworkState().isInternetAvailable) {
            closure(false, Constants.noInternetConnectionString)
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.scoopWhoopProvider.request(.home) { [weak self] result in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    do {
                        
                        if var responseDict = try response.mapJSON() as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                            
                            if let data = responseDict["data"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
                                
                                self.datasource.removeAll()
                                self.dataCount = data.count
                                
                                for (index, dataDict) in data.enumerated() {
                                    
                                    let homeVideosSection = HomeVideosSection(dataDict)
                                    self.datasource.append(homeVideosSection)
                                    
                                    homeVideosSection.fetchDataForSection(index) { [weak self] (success) in
                                        
                                        guard let self = self else { return }
                                        
                                            self.datasource[index] = homeVideosSection
                                            
                                            let dataNotSetSections = self.datasource.filter { (homeVideosSectionObject) -> Bool in
                                                !homeVideosSectionObject.isDataSet
                                            }
                                            
                                            if dataNotSetSections.count == 0 {
                                                
                                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                    closure(true, nil)
                                                }
                                                
                                            } else {

                                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                    closure(false, nil)
                                                }
                                                
                                            }
                                            
                                        } else {
                                            
                                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                closure(false, nil)
                                            }
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    closure(false, nil)
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                        } else {
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                closure(false, nil)
                            }
                            
                        }
                    } catch (let error) {
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            closure(false, error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                        
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        closure(false, error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And `HomeVideosSection`:

```
class HomeVideosSection {
    var section_type: String!
    var value: Value!
    var showDetail: ShowDetail?
    var isDataSet = false
    var datasource = [Any]()
    
    private var provider = MoyaProvider<ScoopWhoop>(plugins: [CompleteUrlLoggerPlugin()])
    
    convenience init(_ dictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        self.init()
        
        section_type = dictionary["section_type"] as? String
        do {
            value = try JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary["value"] as? [String: Any] as Any))
        } catch (let error) {
            print("Error setting section \(section_type ?? "") value : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func fetchDataForSection(_ index: Int, closure: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        print("fetching detail for section : \(section_type ?? "")")

        // fetch details for section types

        if !(NetworkState().isInternetAvailable) {
            closure(false)
            return
        }
        
        var requestType: ScoopWhoop?
        
        if section_type == "app_exclusive" {
            requestType = .appExclusiveVideos(offset: nil)
        } else if section_type == "recently_added" {
            requestType = .videos(offset: nil)
        } else if section_type == "shows" {
            requestType = .shows(offset: nil)
        } else if section_type == "anchors" {
            requestType = .actors(offset: nil)
        } else if section_type == "more_shows" {
            requestType = .filteredShows(offset: nil, filter_slug: value.slug)
        } else if section_type == "sw_shows_video" {
            requestType = .filteredShows(offset: nil, filter_slug: value.slug, filter_type:"show_sw_more")
        } else if section_type == "sw_videos" {
            requestType = .filteredShows(offset: nil, filter_slug: nil, filter_type:"sw_more")
        } else if section_type == "sw_shows" {
            requestType = .scoopwhoopShows(offset: nil)
        } else if section_type == "trending" {
            requestType = .filteredShows(offset: nil, filter_slug: nil, filter_type:"trending")
        } else if section_type == "most_viewed" {
            requestType = .filteredShows(offset: nil, filter_slug: nil, filter_type:"most_viewed")
        } else {
            // unhandled section_type
            self.isDataSet = true
            
            print("Data set for section : \(self.section_type ?? "")")
            
            closure(true)
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if let requestType = requestType {
                
                self.provider.request(requestType) { [weak self] result in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let response):
                        do {
                            if let responseDict = try response.mapJSON() as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                                if let data = responseDict["data"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
                                    
                                    if let showDetails = responseDict["show_details"] as? [String : Any] {
                                        do {
                                            let dataObject = try ShowDetail(dictionary: showDetails)
                                            self.showDetail = dataObject
                                        } catch (let error) {
                                            print("HomeVideoSection ShowDetail object error " + error.localizedDescription)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                    for dataDict in data {
                                        
                                        let dataDict = dataDict
                                        
                                        if self.section_type == "shows" || self.section_type == "sw_shows" {
                                            
                                            do {
                                                let show = try Show(dictionary: dataDict)
                                                self.datasource.append(show)
                                            } catch (let error) {
                                                print("HomeVideoSection Show object error " + error.localizedDescription)
                                            }
                                            
                                        } else if self.section_type == "anchors" {
                                            
                                            do {
                                                let actor = try Anchor(dictionary: dataDict)
                                                self.datasource.append(actor)
                                            } catch (let error) {
                                                print("HomeVideoSection Anchor object error " + error.localizedDescription)
                                            }
                                            
                                        } else {
                                            
                                            do {
                                                let video = try Video(dictionary: dataDict)
                                                self.datasource.append(video)
                                            } catch (let error) {
                                                print("HomeVideoSection Video object error " + error.localizedDescription)
                                            }
                                            
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                    
                                    if self.section_type != "anchors" && self.datasource.count != 0 {
                                        self.datasource.append(ViewMore(title: "View All"))
                                    }
                                    
                                    self.isDataSet = true
                                    
                                    print("Data set for section : \(self.section_type ?? "")")
                                    
                                    closure(true)
                                } else {
                                    print("Data set for section dict map error: \(self.section_type ?? "")")
                                    
                                    closure(false)
                                }
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print("Data set for section JSON map error: \(self.section_type ?? "")")
                            
                            closure(false)
                        }
                    case .failure:
                        print("Data set for section failure: \(self.section_type ?? "")")
                    
                        closure(false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might lie in the way you are using the `init` method. In Swift, the pattern used in Objective-C does not apply anymore, meaning that you should not assign anything to `self`. For instance, if some init would look like this in Objective-C:

```c
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initializing code
    }
    return self;
}
```

in Swift this exact same init would look like:

```swift
init() {
    // Initialize all members defined by this subclass
    super.init()
    // Perform other initialization routines (e.g. call self.configure())
}
```

Notice that the assignment to `self` and the `return self` statements are replaced by a simple `super.init()` call. Another important thing to notice that all the members from the subclass must be initialized before the call to super and the rest of the initialization logic must be after the call to super, rules that simply do not exist in Objective-C. These are rules imposed by Swift to ensure that the initializer is as safe as possible, and there might be a lot of odd side effects if trying to use something different than this standard pattern.

Now, to come back to the issue in the question, I have no proper explanation why your code results in a memory leak other than assigning to `self` is some kind of undefined behaviour.

What would be a good alternative to this is to perform the deserialization in a static method:

```swift
extension Video: Codable {

    static func create(from dictionary: [String: Any]) throws -> Video {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Video.self, from: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary))
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case duration, nsfw, genres, nextVideo, title, video_thumbnail_9x16, onexone_img, video_script, feature_img, sh_heading, tags, alt_content, video_thumbnail_16x9, pub_date, slug, aspect_ratio, _id, interactive, show, cast_crew, srt, sw_more
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As the snippet above using a static method would work just fine, a better solution is to delegate the JSON deserialization into objects to a specialized function/class:

```swift
func decodeJSON<T: Decodable>(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) throws -> T {
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary))
}
```

and let the Swift type inference mechanism to decide what type is `T`:

```
let json = [String: Any]()
let video: Video = try? decodeJSON(json)
```

**UPDATE 2**

The rest of the code looks just fine at a first glance. There is no obvious retain cycle there. I'd suggest to try using `[weak self]` for every closure and check if the leak is still there (it's usually a good habit to capture self weakly, unless you specifically need to keep a strong reference to it). If this does not get rid of the memory leak, then it could from some other place. Just keep in mind that not using the Swift's memory management tools properly results in very weird issues. This might come from a completely unrelated piece of code.

For instance, I once had the application playing random audio, and it turned out to be a leaked instance of a view controller which was registering a delegate to some other service (which had the delegate as strong reference) thus creating a strong reference cycle. The whole audio management was correctly implemented (the audio needed to be played at certain time intervals), and it was pretty hard to be traced. So after some several hours spent on debugging the interaction between the view controller and the audio service I finally spotted where the leak was happening and it was so frustrating that it had absolutely nothing to do with the piece of code that was producing the unexpected behaviour.

So what I want to say with this, after you try a few more things with this specific section of code (which looks pretty fine to me though), try to inspect and clean up the rest of the code, as there are big chances that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I tried your first static method. But it is still giving me leaks on `Video.create(from:)` method. I've used it like below `do {
                                                    let video = try Video.create(from: dataDict)
                                                    self.datasource.append(video)
                                                } catch (let error) {
                                                    print("HomeVideoSection Video object error " + error.localizedDescription)
                                                }`

Comment: Well, then it is quite possible that the leak comes from somewhere else. Try to look to the other allocs in the profiler and check if maybe the `datasource` collection gets deallocated. Also pay much attention to using closures. If you'd like further help, update the question or post another one with the code that creates these `Video` objects, like the place where you trigger the networking call or database call or whatever source it is fetched from. It is most probably a reference cycle that holds all these objects into memory.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've added more code. Please take a look